# Suppress PLSQL message '1 row(s) updated' even when ZERO rows are updated?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

In Oracle APEX 4.2, if I run the following snippet of code...

```
BEGIN
   UPDATE employees
      SET salary = 25000
      WHERE department_id = 999;
   IF SQL%ROWCOUNT = 0 THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(SQL%ROWCOUNT || ' row(s) were updated.');
   END IF;
END;
```

...it returns the following messages...

```
0 row(s) were updated.

1 row(s) updated.
```

The first message of course is my own, but the second message is automatic.

Can the second message be suppressed? If so, how? Why is it seemingly wrong?

We do not have SQL*Plus installed, so I cannot use SET FEEDBACK OFF.

I have googled much for this, and cannot find an answer.

Thank you.

Comment: Where do you increment this variable ? If this is all your code, then ofcourse it will output 0

Comment: What else is being run? That first message looks like it comes from your pl/sql block, but the 2nd message looks like it comes from a direct UPDATE statement (ie. not via PL/SQL).

Comment: The second message is generated by APEX - when you run this block of code in the SQL Workshop's SQL Command window.  But so what?  That is a developer tool, not a UI you would give to end users!

Comment: Yes if you try to run this snippet of code in sqlplus. It will just show once "Rows Updated".